# Tab Navigation in Bootstrap is not Working

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm stuck on making the tabs on my nav bar work with bootstrap. When the tab links are clicked, the URL changes, but the html doesn't change to the new tab. Tabs are clickable and the link changes, but the data doesn't refresh to the new tab. I'm using bootstrap 4. Do I also need to use add Jquery code to make this work? What I'm I doing wrong?

```
    <div class="container mt-5">


        <!--Section: Content-->
        <section class="dark-grey-text text-center">
      
          <style>
            .md-pills .nav-link.active {
              background-color: #3f51b5;
            }
          </style>
          
          <!-- Section heading -->
          <h3 class="font-weight-bold mb-4 pb-2">Our best projects</h3>
          <!-- Section description -->
          <p class="text-muted w-responsive mx-auto mb-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum quas, eos officia maiores ipsam ipsum dolores reiciendis ad voluptas, animi obcaecati adipisci sapiente mollitia. </p>
          
            <!--First row-->
            <div class="row">
              
              <!--First column-->
              <div class="col-12">
                
                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                <ul class="nav md-pills flex-center flex-wrap mx-0" role="tablist">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active font-weight-bold" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel31" role="tab">ALL</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel32" role="tab">BRANDING</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel33" role="tab">PACKAGING</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel34" role="tab">PRINT DESIGN</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                
              </div>
              <!--First column-->
      
          </div>
          <!--First row-->
          
          <!--Tab panels-->
          <div class="tab-content">
      
            <!--Panel 1-->
            <div class="tab-pane fade show in active" id="panel31" role="tabpanel">
      
              <!--First row-->
              <div class="row">
                
                <!--First column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--First column-->
                
                <!--Second column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project8.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--Second column-->
                
                <!--Third column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project4.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--Third column-->
                
              </div>
              <!--First row-->
                            <!--Tab panels-->
          <div class="tab-content">
      
            <!--Panel 1-->
            <div class="tab-pane fade show in active" id="panel31" role="tabpanel">
      
              <!--First row-->
              <div class="row">
                
                <!--First column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--First column-->
                
                <!--Second column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project8.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--Second column-->
                
                <!--Third column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project4.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--Third column-->
                
              </div>
              <!--First row-->
                            <!--Tab panels-->
          <div class="tab-content">
      
            <!--Panel 1-->
            <div class="tab-pane fade show in active" id="panel31" role="tabpanel">
      
              <!--First row-->
              <div class="row">
                
                <!--First column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--First column-->
                
                <!--Second column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project8.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--Second column-->
                
                <!--Third column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project4.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--Third column-->
                
              </div>
              <!--First row-->
      
            </div>
            <!--Panel 1-->
      
            <!--Panel 2-->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="panel32" role="tabpanel">
      
              <!--First row-->
              <div class="row">
                
                <!--First column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project4.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--First column-->
                
                <!--Second column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project5.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--Second column-->
                
                <!--Third column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--Third column-->
                
              </div>
              <!--First row-->
      
            </div>
            <!--Panel 2-->
      
            <!--Panel 3-->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="panel33" role="tabpanel">
      
              <!--First row-->
              <div class="row">
                
                <!--First column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project3.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--First column-->
                
                <!--Second column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project6.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--Second column-->
                
                <!--Third column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project8.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--Third column-->
      
              </div>
              <!--First row-->
      
            </div>
            <!--Panel 3-->
      
            <!--Panel 4-->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="panel34" role="tabpanel">
      
              <!--First row-->
              <div class="row">
                
                <!--First column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--First column-->
                
                <!--Second column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project7.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--Second column-->
                
                <!--Third column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project8.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--Third column-->
                
              </div>
              <!--First row-->
      
            </div>
            <!--Panel 4-->
      
          </div>
          <!--Tab panels-->
      
          </section>
        
        
      </div>
```

Comment: Some bootstrap functions do require jQuery & bootstrap.js, checkout their documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

You are add panel-1 at **3 times**  remove and add **[Bootstrap CSS and JS CDN](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/).**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container mt-5">


        <!--Section: Content-->
        <section class="dark-grey-text text-center">
      
          <style>
            .md-pills .nav-link.active {
              background-color: #3f51b5;
            }
          </style>
          
          <!-- Section heading -->
          <h3 class="font-weight-bold mb-4 pb-2">Our best projects</h3>
          <!-- Section description -->
          <p class="text-muted w-responsive mx-auto mb-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum quas, eos officia maiores ipsam ipsum dolores reiciendis ad voluptas, animi obcaecati adipisci sapiente mollitia. </p>
          
            <!--First row-->
            <div class="row">
              
              <!--First column-->
              <div class="col-12">
                
                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                <ul class="nav md-pills flex-center flex-wrap mx-0" role="tablist">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active font-weight-bold" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel31" role="tab">ALL</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel32" role="tab">BRANDING</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel33" role="tab">PACKAGING</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel34" role="tab">PRINT DESIGN</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                
              </div>
              <!--First column-->
      
          </div>
          <!--First row-->
          
          <!--Tab panels-->
          <div class="tab-content">
      
    
      
         
            <!--Panel 1-->
            <div class="tab-pane fade show in active" id="panel31" role="tabpanel">
      
              <!--First row-->
              <div class="row">
                
                <!--First column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--First column-->
                
                <!--Second column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project8.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--Second column-->
                
                <!--Third column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project4.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--Third column-->
                
              </div>
              <!--First row-->
      
            </div>
            <!--Panel 1-->
      
            <!--Panel 2-->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="panel32" role="tabpanel">
      
              <!--First row-->
              <div class="row">
                
                <!--First column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project4.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--First column-->
                
                <!--Second column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project5.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--Second column-->
                
                <!--Third column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--Third column-->
                
              </div>
              <!--First row-->
      
            </div>
            <!--Panel 2-->
      
            <!--Panel 3-->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="panel33" role="tabpanel">
      
              <!--First row-->
              <div class="row">
                
                <!--First column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project3.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--First column-->
                
                <!--Second column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project6.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--Second column-->
                
                <!--Third column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project8.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--Third column-->
      
              </div>
              <!--First row-->
      
            </div>
            <!--Panel 3-->
      
            <!--Panel 4-->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="panel34" role="tabpanel">
      
              <!--First row-->
              <div class="row">
                
                <!--First column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--First column-->
                
                <!--Second column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project7.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--Second column-->
                
                <!--Third column-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                  <!--Featured image-->
                  <div class="view overlay zoom z-depth-2">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/project8.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold text-muted my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet</p>
                </div>
                <!--Third column-->
                
              </div>
              <!--First row-->
      
            </div>
            <!--Panel 4-->
      
          </div>
          <!--Tab panels-->
      
          </section>
        
        
      </div>
```